# Map n string values to int column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this where a column have alphanumerical values. Now I want to map all those values to some integer and also have some dictionary where I have those mappings so I can use them later. They're not all unique values.

```
column
  a
  c1
  3vc
  c1
  .
  .
  .
  n
```

Output:

```
column
  1
  2
  3
  2
  .
  .
  .
  n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no special requirement for the mapping order, you can directly sort the rankings according to the character order to map to integers.

```
data = [
    ('a',),
    ('c1',),
    ('3vc',),
    ('a',),
    ('c1',),
    ('fd',)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['column'])
df = df.selectExpr('column', 'dense_rank() over (order by column) as int_col') \
    .withColumn('mapping', F.expr('map(column, int_col)'))
df.show(truncate=False)

# +------+-------+----------+
# |column|int_col|mapping   |
# +------+-------+----------+
# |3vc   |1      |{3vc -> 1}|
# |a     |2      |{a -> 2}  |
# |a     |2      |{a -> 2}  |
# |c1    |3      |{c1 -> 3} |
# |c1    |3      |{c1 -> 3} |
# |fd    |4      |{fd -> 4} |
# +------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thnaks man, this was really helpful!

Comment: Hey, this does change my partition to just 1, and I can repartition later but that's creating problem while saving as rank step has just one partition and it's not dividing the stage into multiple task. Is there any other way I can do it.